yarn dev hangs on "Linking dependencies"
I have just started working on a reactjs application, and found that I cannot run the app using yarn on localhost at all, as it hangs after reaching "Linking dependencies". I am running this on a laptop and the repo is in C:\FolderName\FolderName\automatarium, which appears to have correct access control.
Here is the output I get (it's the same when I run verbose mode).
yarn run v1.22.22
$ yarn dev:frontend
$ concurrently "yarn watch:packages" "yarn workspace frontend start"
$ concurrently "yarn watch:simulation -p 1235" "yarn watch:jflap-translator -p 1236"
$ parcel public/index.html --no-cache
$ yarn workspace @automatarium/simulation watch -p 1235
$ yarn workspace @automatarium/jflap-translator watch -p 1236
$ parcel watch -p 1235
$ parcel watch -p 1236
[1] 
[1] console: (node:2292) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
[1] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[0] [1] 
[0] [0]
[0] [1] console: (node:17024) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
[0] [1] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[0] [0] console: (node:19512) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.        
[0] [0] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1] Server running at http://localhost:1234
[1] Building...
[0] [1] Building...
[0] [0] Building...
[0] [0] 
[0] [0] console: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
[0] [0]   npx update-browserslist-db@latest
[0] [0]   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
[0] [1]
[0] [1] console: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
[0] [1]   npx update-browserslist-db@latest
[0] [1]   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
[1] 
[1] console: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
[1]   npx update-browserslist-db@latest
[1]   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
[0] [0] Bundling...
[1] Installing buffer...
[0] [0] Packaging & Optimizing...
[0] [0] ✨ Built in 2.05s
[1] yarn: [1/4] Resolving packages
[1] yarn: [2/4] Fetching packages
[1] yarn: [3/4] Linking dependencies
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-00347754-e1fd-4f72-97fa-d0c90446f284 > @parcel/transformer-typescript-types@2.8.3" has unmet
[1] peer dependency "typescript@>=3.0.0".
[1]
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-00347754-e1fd-4f72-97fa-d0c90446f284 > frontend > goober@2.1.12" has unmet peer dependency

[1] "csstype@^3.0.10".
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-00347754-e1fd-4f72-97fa-d0c90446f284 > @automatarium/jflap-translator > ts-jest@29.1.0" has
[1] unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=4.3 <6".
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-00347754-e1fd-4f72-97fa-d0c90446f284 > @automatarium/jflap-translator > ts-node@10.9.1" has
[1] unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-00347754-e1fd-4f72-97fa-d0c90446f284 > @automatarium/jflap-translator > ts-node@10.9.1" has
[1] unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.7".
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-00347754-e1fd-4f72-97fa-d0c90446f284 > @parcel/transformer-typescript-types >
[1] @parcel/ts-utils@2.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=3.0.0".
[0] [1] Bundling...
[0] [1] Packaging & Optimizing...
[0] [1] ✨ Built in 6.74s

It then freezes for about 15 mins before giving this output:
[1] 
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
[1] 'C:UsersMyUsernameDocumentsAutomatariumautomatariumnodemodules@parcelfsnodemodules@parcelwatcherprebuildswin32-x64node.napi.glibc.node'
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
[1] Installing stream-browserify...
[1] yarn: [1/4] Resolving packages
[1] yarn: [2/4] Fetching packages
[1] yarn: [3/4] Linking dependencies
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-7324cc79-b752-4faa-889a-e821ed755e90 > @parcel/transformer-typescript-types@2.8.3" has unmet
[1] peer dependency "typescript@>=3.0.0".
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-7324cc79-b752-4faa-889a-e821ed755e90 > frontend > goober@2.1.12" has unmet peer dependency

[1] "csstype@^3.0.10".
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-7324cc79-b752-4faa-889a-e821ed755e90 > @automatarium/jflap-translator > ts-jest@29.1.0" has
[1] unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=4.3 <6".
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-7324cc79-b752-4faa-889a-e821ed755e90 > @automatarium/jflap-translator > ts-node@10.9.1" has
[1] unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-7324cc79-b752-4faa-889a-e821ed755e90 > @automatarium/jflap-translator > ts-node@10.9.1" has
[1] unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.7".
[1] @parcel/package-manager: yarn: "workspace-aggregator-7324cc79-b752-4faa-889a-e821ed755e90 > @parcel/transformer-typescript-types >
[1] @parcel/ts-utils@2.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=3.0.0".

Completely stumped on this one, have tried altering security of folders, uninstalling and reinstalling yarn and npm, clearing yarn cache and reinstalling repo. No luck.
TLDR: Tried running yarn install from root folder, which worked fine, then yarn dev, which hung at "Linking dependencies" and gives eperm error.
EDIT: After letting yarn dev run for an hour it finally builds, but now when I close the server and try again it gives a different error:
yarn run v1.22.22
$ yarn dev:frontend
$ concurrently "yarn watch:packages" "yarn workspace frontend start"
$ concurrently "yarn watch:simulation -p 1235" "yarn watch:jflap-translator -p 1236"
$ parcel public/index.html --no-cache
$ yarn workspace @automatarium/simulation watch -p 1235
$ yarn workspace @automatarium/jflap-translator watch -p 1236
$ parcel watch -p 1235
$ parcel watch -p 1236
[1] Server running at http://localhost:1234 
[0] error: unknown option `-p'
[0] [1] error: unknown option `-p'
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
[0] [0] Exit code: 1
[0] [0] Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
[0] [0] Arguments: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js watch -p 1235
[0] [0] Directory: C:\Folder\2024-PP\automatarium\packages\simulation
[0] [0] Output:
[0] [0]
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
[0] [1] Exit code: 1
[0] [1] Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
[0] [1] Arguments: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js watch -p 1236
[0] [1] Directory: C:\Folder\2024-PP\automatarium\packages\jflap-translator
[0] [1] Output:
[0] [1]
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
[0] [0] yarn watch:simulation -p 1235 exited with code 1
[0] [1] yarn watch:jflap-translator -p 1236 exited with code 1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
[0] yarn watch:packages exited with code 1
[1] ×  C:\Folder\2024-PP\automatarium\frontend\public\src\index.tsx: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Folder\2024-PP\automatarium\frontend\public\src\index.tsx'
[1] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Folder\2024-PP\automatarium\frontend\public\src\index.tsx'

